# Marmap library grid file to xyz

Tags: grid

I have a .grd file of bathymetric data with good quality that I would like to use in marmap, but my original file is a grid. As I understood from the vignette, I must have  the data in a .xyz file for this library. Some one can tell me how to read and open this file straightforward from the ori«ginal file  using this library?
data is here: http://w3.ualg.pt/~jluis/mirone/data-links.html (Bat do Algarve a 50m)
?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your .grd file is in fact a netCDF file. To create an object of class `bathy` to use with marmap, do the following:

```
library(ncdf)
dat <- open.ncdf("algarve50.grd")

x <- get.var.ncdf(dat,varid="x")
y <- get.var.ncdf(dat,varid="y")
z <- get.var.ncdf(dat,varid="z")

mat <- matrix(z, byrow=FALSE, nrow=length(x), dimnames=list(x,y))
class(mat) <- "bathy"
```

Then, to plot, use:

```
library(marmap)
library(RColorBrewer)  # For nice color palettes

plot(mat, land = TRUE, n = 1, lwd = 0.3, image = TRUE, 
     bpal = list(c(min(mat), 0, rev(brewer.pal(9,"Blues"))),
             c(0, max(mat), grey(seq(.7,.1,-.05)))))
```

Warning: your bathy object is pretty big (almost 5 million cells!) so plotting might take some time. Anyway, here is the result:[image]

Comment: thank you very much Benoit, very helpful answer. Now, I came out with a new question, how to subset this bathy file? I have try this:

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to use the `subsetBathy()` function after you created the first bathy object (called `mat` in my answer above). You can use the function either in interactive mode by directly clicking on the map (twice to define a rectangular area, or more than twice to get a polygon of any shape), or in non-interactive mode by entering manually the coordinates of the bounding box for the desired area. For instance, to zoom in on the Ria Formosa:

```
ria.formosa <- subsetBathy(mat, x=c(-8,-7.7), y=c(36.9,37.1), locator=F)
plot(ria.formosa)
summary(ria.formosa)

Bathymetric data of class 'bathy', with 601 rows and 401 columns
Latitudinal range: 36.9 to 37.1 (36.9 N to 37.1 N)
Longitudinal range: -8 to -7.7 (8 W to 7.7 W)
Cell size: 0 minute(s)

Depth statistics:
    Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. 
-768.800  -73.820   -2.332  -36.330   17.140  363.600 

First 5 columns and rows of the bathymetric matrix:
             36.9   36.9005    36.901   36.9015    36.902
-8      -89.86719 -89.46094 -89.03516 -88.62500 -88.19922
-7.9995 -89.89062 -89.47266 -89.03516 -88.60938 -88.19531
-7.999  -89.89453 -89.46094 -89.03906 -88.59375 -88.18750
-7.9985 -89.90625 -89.47656 -89.03906 -88.58984 -88.15625
-7.998  -89.89844 -89.45703 -89.02734 -88.58594 -88.15625
```